# Solid State Drive Reformatting Limit

Tags: ssd, formatting, storage

Is there a limit on the amount of times you can format a Solid State Drive, until you see effects? I was trying to install a program, to go back to original settings; long story short, I ended reformatting computer 3 times, deleting all partitions and reinstalling windows from a boot drive. Just curious if anyone has idea, since formatting is one of the more write heavy operations.
Thanks,

Comment: You haven't really.

Comment: what else should I add for description? "deleting all partitions and reinstalling windows from a boot drive'

Comment: That does far less to the drive than you think.

Comment: simply wipe a few bytes in the MBR or GPT header will "format" your drives. And unless you do a full format, which zeros out the whole drive and takes a significant amount of time, by default Windows does a quick format which just delete all files or recreate the metadata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends somewhat on the drive, but generally speaking SSD's are a lot more robust when it comes to write cycles then people imagine - with over 1000 full disk writes being conservative in the real world. Have a read of https://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead

Also, formatting could imply overwriting the whole disk, but almost all formatting done on modern systems is a quick format which does not actually write much data, so it's not very hard on your drive.